# GwtTestCase and Spring

Tags: gwt, spring-mvc, gwttestcase

So I managed to create a GWT-SpringMVC setup. Wasn't easy (not too many resources), but possible. I even autowired and stuff. It even works :)

However, I can't figure out how to make the GwtTestCase run. Obviously it needs the "server" to be up, and because I use Spring, it needs to pass through the dispatching servlet (no?). But I can't figure out how to connect the two. In production or hosted mode, I got the web.xml and the spring-servlet.xml to configure these things. What can I do for tests?

I thought of ignoring the web part and testing the service directly - but this will deny me the option to automatically tests that everything is "transferable".
(if you have an idea on how to do that, I might ditch the GWTTestCase altogether).

Comment: Your basic assumptions are incorrect - `GwtTestCase` dos not require the server to be up at all; it's for writing unit tests.

Comment: @skaffman: I thought that GWTTestCase worked on the javascript level. How can I check that if the server is down?

Comment: Because javascript has nothing to do with the server. `GwtTestCase` starts up a headless browser engine and runs the JS inside of that. The server is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @skaffman: so how can I check that my client/server integration is working? that all of my "shared" classes are "transferable"?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to GWTTestCase could be the [gwt-test-utils](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/) framework, which provides a simple integration with Spring (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/wiki/HowToUseWithSpring) for details)